# Windows phone 8 Emulator and copying test images to CameraRoll

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'd like to copy some images to the windows phone 8 emulator, but can't seem to find a way to do this.

I was hoping when the emulator was running I would be able to access certain directorys via windows as per a real device.

Any ideas, I can't help thinking I'm missing something.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently detailed how to do that in that blog post:

> [How to add images on the Windows Phone emulator](https://web.archive.org/web/20160329201319/http://www.softwareisinthedetails.com/2012/11/add-test-images-on-windows-phone-emulator.html)

Comment: Do you ever get exceptions thrown seemingly random when copying files across?

Comment: No. What exception do you get?

Comment: Just a random object reference, a couple of other guys have mentioned it on connect and it's been raised as a repeatable issue.

Comment: This is a gem indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Check power tools.You can copy images with this tool.
http://wptools.codeplex.com/